shouldn't this need a function based index?
cd_col of table1 has regular single column btree index, but when I am querying cd_col using split_part function, I assumed it shouldn't use the btree index, but it does use. Shouldn't it need a function based index for it work? This is version 15.3.
postgres=> explain select * from schema1.table1 where cd_col = 'abc';
                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using ix_table1 on table1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=2414)
   Index Cond: ((cd_col)::text = 'abc'::text)
(2 rows)

postgres=> explain select * from schema1.table1 where cd_col = split_part('abc|xyz','|',1);
                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using ix_table1 on table1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=2414)
   Index Cond: ((cd_col)::text = 'abc'::text)
(2 rows)

postgres=> \set id '\'abc|xyz\''
postgres=> explain select * from schema1.table1 where cd_col = split_part(:id,'|',1);
                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using ix_table1 on table1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=2414)
   Index Cond: ((cd_col)::text = 'abc'::text)
(2 rows)

postgres=> \echo :id
'abc|xyz'


If split_part were applied to the column, that would be a problem. But since all of its arguments are literals and since it is immutable, it can be evaluated up front.

That's constant folding.
Your function call was pre-evaluated and as you can see in the resulting query plan, split_part() is no longer present and will not be called during execution at all. Planner/Optimizer correctly noticed that it's enough to run it once, prior to that, and then re-use the result as a constant.
The only function left is texteq() behind = operator, which B-Trees have no problem with.
